# General term of $a_{n}= \sqrt{ a_{n-1}+6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the general term of  $a_{n}= \sqrt{ a_{n-1}+6}$,$a_{1}=4$?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a closed form for this recursion?  I rather doubt that there is.  $a_n$ is a nested radical which is a root of a polynomial of degree $2^{n-1}$, and these seem to be irreducible over the rationals.

Comment: where is the deleted response?

Comment: @user32240: I got here in time to see the first answer before it was deleted - it was just incorrect (it solved the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2}$ instead of what's in the question).

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: I see! I was thinking this is a truly magic proof, utilizing methods I barely know. I only remember people use characteristic polynomials to solve Fibonacci sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Working out a few elements of the sequence:

$$a_1 = 4 \\
a_2 = \sqrt {10} \\
a_3 = \sqrt {6 + \sqrt {10}} \\
a_4 = \sqrt {6 + \sqrt {6 + \sqrt{10}}} \\
\vdots \\
a_n = \sqrt {6 + \sqrt {6 + \sqrt {\cdots + \sqrt{10} }} }
$$

I am guessing you can't easily get a "closed-form" expression for the general term. (The reason I guess this is that the minimal degree of the field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ that contains $a_n$ is unbounded with $n$. If someone reading this disagrees with me I would like to hear it :) )

However, maybe you don't need the general term. I remember having exercises that look like this one in calculus courses, where the question wasn't "find the general term" but rather "find the limit". If that's your question, here's a strategy:

1. Figure out what the *possible* limits are. (Assume the sequence has a limit and use the recurrence to rule out all values except two.)
2. Guess what it really is (i.e. using a calculator).
3. Show that the sequence is monotonous (descending).
4. Show that the sequence is always greater than the guessed limit. (Use induction.)
5. Deduce the limit from the above.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if such general closed form exists.

We have $\sqrt{a_{n-1}+6}$ to be $\sqrt{10}$ in the first step, and $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{10}}$ is hard to simplify as if one assume it has the form $a+\sqrt{b}$, then we must have $a^{2}+b=6,2a\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{10}$. This force $a^{2}b=5/2$, and one has to solve $x^{2}-6x+5/2$. This gives $a^{2}$ or $b$ equal to $\frac{6+\sqrt{36-10}}{2}=3+\frac{\sqrt{23}}{2}$, which is fairly ugly. Another guess might be $\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$, but then we would have $6=c+d$ and $10=4cd$, which ends up to the same thing. Since $a_{2}$ is already such a mess it is hard to come up with general formula for $a_{i}$.